# Chi-square distribution Verification

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

*I know there is one answer for this question, but I just changed my question a little bit...so please read it*

By Definition, Let ν be a positive integer. A random variable Y is said to have a chi-square distribution with ν degrees of freedom if and only if Y is a gamma-distributed random variable with parameters α = ν/2 and β = 2.

By Thm, If Y is a chi-square random variable with ν degrees of freedom, then
μ = E(Y) = ν and $σ^2$ = V(Y) = 2ν.

The question to test whether Y, $E(Y) = 10$ and $E[(1+Y)^2] = 36$ has a chi-square distribution?

(1) Whether $E(Y) = 10$, $E[(1+Y)^2] = 36$ have a chi-square distribution? Explain why, why not, or cannot be determined.

My approach was

$E(Y^2) = V(Y)+[E(Y)]^2 = 2*10 + 10^2 = 120
$E(Y) = 10, E[(1+Y)^2] = E[1+2Y+Y^2] = E(1) + 2E(Y) + E(Y^2) = 1 + 2*10 + 120 = 141 $
Therefore, this is a not chi-square distribution.

(2)Whether $E(Y) = 10$, $E[(1+Y)^2] = 51$ have a chi-square distribution? Explain why, why not, or cannot be determined.
For the same reasoning above, this is a not chi-square distribution.

However, after taking a closer look of the question: the question is asking whether Y, $E(Y)=10$ and $E[(1+Y)2]=36$, have a chi-square distribution...however, by definition, a random variable Y is said to have a chi-square distribution with ν degrees of freedom if and only if Y is a gamma-distributed random variable with parameters α = ν/2 and β = 2. ...

The question we need to answer does not mention anything about with degrees of freedom...so is my argument with using parameters α = ν/2 and β = 2 valid?

If valid, am my approach right? If not, what is the right approach? If so, is there any other ways to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $E(Y)$ and $E(1+Y)^2$, you want to know if $Y$ is a Chi-square random variate. Note that Chi-Square distribution is a special form of Gamma distribution with a specific choice of Gamma parameters, as you have mentioned. So, don't worry about the Gamma distribution for your problem. Just use the property of the Chi-square distribution that for any Chi-Square random variate $X$, variance of $X$ is twice the expectation of $X$. Thus, if you can show that $2E(Y) \ne V(Y)$, you can straightway comment that $Y$ is NOT a Chi-square variate. [Note: $V(Y)$ itself doesn't exist as it is negative for your given problem]

PS: A counter-example is good enough to disprove a conjecture

Comment: Does the way I show work? A follow up question if $E(Y) = 10$, $E[(1+Y)^2] = 141$ ....could we conclude that Y has chi - squared distribution ...if yes, why? If not, why not? I think it cannot be determined because this could be a  coincidence that Y has that same mean and variance but not necessarily has chi-square distribution ....if this is a right answer, is there a better way to say the reason...

Comment: The way you have shown that $Y$ is not a chi-squared variate is fine. But note that this is just a verification and (fortunately!) a proof too because it is a counter-example. You have started by assuming something and ended up saying your assumption is incorrect. However, you can't comment on $Y$ having any distribution simply from the the first two moments. For example, $Y$ could be drawn from a Normal distribution with mean $10$ and variance $20$.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong: even if $E(Y)$ = 10, $E[(1+Y)^2] = 141, we still cannot determine whether Y has chi-squared distibution or not because Y could have a normal distribution with the same means and variance?

Comment: That's right! Any two distributions may coincidentally have same mean and variance. Are you convinced now?

Answer (score 1):

That looks reasonable.  In effect you have said:

> A random variable whose distribution does not have $E[(1+Y)^2] = 1 + 4E[Y]^2 + E[Y^2]$ does not have a chi-square distribution.

Of course the converse is not necessarily correct.

A different method would be to say that more generally $E[(1+Y)^2] \ge (1+ E[Y])^2 = 121$ if  $E[Y]=10$ so neither of the distributions in the question are meaningful (and therefore are not chi-square).  At this point you should check that you have read the question properly.

Comment: You mean $E[(1+Y)^2] = 1 + 2E[Y]+ E[Y^2]$?

Comment: Also, I am a little bit confused...do I need to change any of my reasoning ? Also, when you said I should read the question carefully, did I miss anything from the question?

Comment: Yes to your first comment.  On your second, the question looks implausible: not only are they not a chi-square distribution, they are not any distribution.  So it is worth checking the question.

Comment: Do you mean both  E(Y) = 10, E[(1+Y)^2] = 36 and E(Y) = 10, E[(1+Y)^2] = 51 not a chi-square distribution...in fact they are not any distribution ? If so, is my reasoning above enough for showing that they are not chi-squared distribution. If not, could you suggest some ways to do that?

Comment: In answer to your three questions: (a) Yes, that is precisely what I mean.  (b) You were checking whether you had 10 and 141, so your conclusion was reasonable. (c) You do not have to do any more.

Comment: I just take a closer look of the question: the question is asking whether Y, $E(Y) =10$ and $E[(1+Y)^2]= 36$, have a chi-square distibution...however, by definition, a random variable Y is said to have a chi-square distribution with ν degrees of freedom if and only if Y is a gamma-distributed random variable with parameters α = ν/2 and β = 2. ...my question does not mention anything about with degrees of freedom...so is my argument with using parameters α = ν/2 and β = 2 valid?

Comment: I just took a closer look at the definition, Let ν be a positive integer. A random variable Y is said to have a chi-square distribution with ν degrees of freedom if and only if Y is a gamma-distributed random variable with parameters α = ν/2 and β = 2....can we determined whether Y is a gamma-distributed variable with just E(Y) and $E[(1+Y)^2]?

Comment: @afsdf dfsaf: You cannot determine that $Y$ has a chi-square distribution just from two moments, but you can determine that the moments are inconsistent with $Y$ having  a chi-square distribution.